# Membership and role authentication to use customized table

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, roleprovider

I'm using asp.net mvc 3, My problem is I need to use the customized users login table instead of using the my_aspnet_users auto generated. How can i point the Membership and role authentication to use the users login table I created. I've found this blog [Customized Membership and Role Provider](http://www.mattwrock.com/post/2009/10/14/Implementing-custom-Membership-Provider-and-Role-Provider-for-Authinticating-ASPNET-MVC-Applications.aspx). but this is for customized membership and role authentication. i just need to point the provider to use the table i created. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: XY Problem. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378 WHY do you need it to point to another table?

Comment: Probably because the schema for the aspnet_* auto-generated stuff is vomit-inducing...

Comment: @ErikPhilips - This is pretty typical for any company that has been around for a while and already has some centralized user store. For many reasons (not all of them technical) it isn't always possible to use the built in table structure. Again, custom membership providers are nothing to be afraid of.

Comment: @TiesonT. : agreed. Bleurgh. Wrong in so many ways.

Comment: @Erik - the built in schema for asp.net is not fit for my existing db(we dont have userid(column)) schema. but i can use the authentication for username and password for asp.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The out-of-the-box [`SqlMembershipProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider.aspx) really doesn't work like that. It is designed to look for very specific stored procedures, and the schema that goes with it. **You can't really "plug" another schema into it** and expect it to work.

That being said, implementing a custom membership provider really isn't all that daunting a task. I've done it numerous times, and you needn't implement everything.

The [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx) are a good place to start, and will walk you through what is required.

Answer (score 3):

How about sticking with standard `MembershipProvider`, and mapping your `Users` table to the generated one (probably by username)?

Comment: thanks for the reply spender - Yes i can, but my user table dont have userid column. Our DBA dont like having an id auto_increment which is standard for large scale DB.

Comment: Why do you need an auto-incrementing id column to perform this mapping? You simply need an extra column in your `Users` table that contains something unique in the aspnet_users table. No id column? That's a strange decision.

Comment: thanks spender, i got what you mean. for the id column, it's not my decision. the dba requested it.